# Растягивание Высоты , Резина

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Здравствуйте!

Реализовал резиновый дизайн. Растягивается ширина, но длина по % не растягивается. Возможно ли это реализовать? Или так и задумано, растягивание только на ширину ?

Подумал что можно задать разную высоты посредством `@media` запросов, так ли это делается или я что-то не так понимаю?

```
height родителя задал в пикселях 
А блок который должен растянуться в процентах
```

Спасибо за время.

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов:
1) как вы написали - задать фиксированную высоту родительскому элементу и масштабировать дочерние от неё. Довольно муторное решение

2) воспользоваться javascript для масштабирования блоков по вертикали. Минус данного способа в том, что у пользователей с отключённым js всё сломается + лишний код писать.

3) воспользоваться css свойством `display: flex`. Единственный пожалуй минус - у пользователей Internet Explorer младше 10 будет также ломаться разметка, но если они важны, то можно использовать js ;)
ссылка на flex: http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: да , вкурсе про flex , но вот только как я написал , почему то не получается )) Ищу иголку в стоге сена

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос проблемную часть разметки, а дальше уже посмотрим

Answer (score 0):

Если вы разметили ширину, то браузер самостоятельно определит и покажет соответствующую высоту. Нет необходимости указывать это. Но, если вы всё таки желаете указать высоту, то примените стили **height:auto** [Инфо W3](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)

Answer (score 0):

innerDiv будет 10px

```
<div style="height:50px">
    <div id="innerDiv" style="height:auto">
          <div id="evenInner" style="height:10px">
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

В CSS3 появились такие интересные единицы измерения как vw и vh - они позволяют устанавливать размеры элементов в зависимости от размера экрана. Таким образом, например, блок с height: 100vh на любом устройстве будет иметь высоту во весь размер экрана (50vh, соответственно, в половину экрана и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в css:

```
html, body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
```

и все получиться как вы задумали